# modeset: problems on booting and external monitor

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, nouveau, nomodeset

Here is my problem.

When I add "**nomodeset**" option to /etc/default/grub in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, my laptop fails to recognize
external monitor. No external monitor under system display setting.
And there are always multiple background compiz processes running with constant noises (from fan). When I remove "nomodeset" option, my ubuntu sometimes (not always) hangs on booting (on the loading page).

It seems that this might result from **nouveau driver**, but I'm not sure. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated!